# How to access individuals rows after GROUP BY with phonegap and sqlite

Tags: javascript, cordova, sqlite

I know this is a fairly simple question. I have been using google to no avail. I want to be able to use a SQL Query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM the_table GROUP BY attr
```

When I access the results of this query I seem to just get one element per attr. Is there any way to get groups of items which I can access each element of? Thanks

Comment: Please provide an example of the output you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Getting one record per group is the whole purpose of `GROUP BY`.

If you want to get all records, try `ORDER BY attr` instead.